# Use of Single Quotes Before Column Name Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I am told to edit existing codes which was written five years ago by five different programmers and I found single quotation marks just right before the name of a column in some query. What is the use of it? I never used Oracle database before... The part of the query looked like this `' ' work_instance`, half of the code is just like below :

```
select PR.request_id, 
       PR.investor_id, 
       PR.proposal_date,
       ' ' work_instance,    
       INV.foreign_company_name name,  
       PR.is_remove_cancel,   
       PR.remove_cancel_number,
       PR.status_id, 
       REFR.description, 
       PR.fo_id, 
       PR.staff_id, 
       PR.case_id,
       PR.sub_department_head_id, 
       PR.director_id, 
       ROUND((sysdate-PR.proposal_date)) as processing_time 
from REMOVAL.request PR,
     KPPA.foreign_company_kp INV,
     REMOVAL.ref_t_status_workflow REFR 
where ...criteria here...
```

Thank you for all of your help, wish you all the best!

Comment: It just indicates that all the rows in the result set of the SELECT query will have `'  '` as value under the column `work_instance`. It is just an assignment of constant value for all the rows in the result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`' ' work_instance` selects a constant string value consisting of a single space and assigns the column alias `work_instance` to that value.

It's the same concept as

```
ROUND((sysdate-PR.proposal_date)) as processing_time
```

With the difference that the actual value isn't taken from a real column, but is a constant value and that the (optional) `as` keyword has not been used.

Comment: So, which means there will be an extra column in the recordset which values are empty strings in every row? Sorry for the late reply @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name, that really helps!